# After upgrading PHP 7.2 to 7.3 php command line not working. bin/magento must be run as a cli application error

Tags: php, command-line, php-7.3

After upgrading the hosting plan, php version migrated from 7.2 to 7.3 (server no longer supports 7.2) and I can't run the php commands any more.

I have tried all the top 10 solutions on Google to fix cli vs cgi-fcgi without success.

Magento 2.35-p2

Any idea?

For example, a simple command for flushing magento cache:

[image]

Comment: Magento version?

Comment: Magento 2.35-p2

Comment: what u tried yet? please list all commands

Comment: nothing works... none of the php command work... once on root, any php command returns the same answer: bin/magento must be run as a CLI application

Comment: [SOLVED] the issue was on PHP path. After getting the right on, I could access the commands. In my case, /opt/alt/php73/usr/bin/php